# Installing a perl application along with the supporting modules onto a Windows PC that doesn't have a compiler

Tags: windows, perl, installation, module

I'm building a perl application that interacts with a PostgreSQL database via the DBD::Pg module, and that uses Perl/Tk for it's GUI. It works fairly well on my system, but I'm designing it for a family member to use for their business. They don't have a c++ compiler and don't have a clue what CPAN is. The goal is to not bog them down by having to load a c++ compiler and go to all of the trouble of building a module from source if I can avoid it.

I need to get the Tk module installed onto their computer along with Strawberry Perl (it includes DBD:Pg right out of the box). How do I go about including this module along with my application in order to make things easier on for my end user? Would simply copying my entire C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\Tk folder into their computer during setup do the trick or does perl need more than that in order to use Tk and be happy with it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to convert your application to an executable, using tools like [perlapp](http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/6.0/PerlApp_overview.html), [perl2exe](http://www.indigostar.com/perl2exe.php), or [par](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR). If not, i think you can try Strawberry Perl [portable](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PAR::Packer) module.
it generates exe on windows with a [simple shell command](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/pp).

```
> pp -o test.exe test.pl
```